# Is there a terser way to bind a method to `this` (than wrapping in a `this`-capturing lambda)?

Tags: c++

I frequently write this kind of code:

```
auto that = this;
functor([that](auto arg1, auto arg2, auto arg3){
    return that->method(arg1, arg2, arg3);
});
```

It would have been nice to just write this instead:

```
functor(method);
```

but the compiler doesn't automatically bind `method` to `this`.

Is there a shorter way to do it (than what I did above), without incurring run time overhead?

Comment: Maybe [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front)?

Comment: @HenriMenke yes exactly. (Unfortunately that is only in C++20.)

Comment: Before C++20 you'd have to use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and enumerate all the arguments with placeholders.  Or you write your own binder, but maybe Boost already has something.

Comment: What about using a macro?